# How to check & classify if key in json array has same value?

Tags: javascript, react-native, sorting

I want to classify same time meetings into different groups. How to do that?

I have been able to identify same time meetings and pushed them into temp array.

But all of them are coming in temp array.

Below is the response.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1081",
    "endDate": "2020-03-24T12:30:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-24T12:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Meeting 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "1073",
    "endDate": "2020-03-24T13:00:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-24T12:30:00.000Z",
    "title": "Meeting 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "1082"
    "endDate": "2020-03-24T12:30:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-24T12:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Event 2",
  },
  {
    "id": "1083"
    "endDate": "2020-03-24T13:00:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-24T12:30:00.000Z",
    "description": "",
    "title": "event 1",
  },
  {

    "id": "1050",
    "endDate": "2020-03-25T13:00:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-25T12:30:00.000Z",
    "title": "event 2",
  }
]
```

I have used following snippet to get meetings with same time.

```
events.sort(function(a, b) {
              return a.startDate < b.startDate
                ? -1
                : a.startDate > b.startDate
                ? 1
                : 0;
            });
            for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              const startDate = events[i].startDate;
              for (let j = i + 1; j < events.length; j++) {
                const startDateNext = events[j].startDate;

                if (startDate === startDateNext) {
                  console.log("ONCE: ", events[j]);
                  flag++;
                  console.log('Array Element %d and %d are equal', i, j);

                }
              }
            }
            console.log('\nThe Equal Numbers In The Array Are = %d', flag);
            console.log('All Events: ', JSON.stringify(events));
            console.log('Events same time: ', eventsWithSameTime);
```

Output:

Array Element 0 & 2 are equal

Array Element 1 & 3 are equal

Array Element 1 & 4 are equal

Array Element 3 & 4 are equal

I want to group meetings like: [0,2] & [1,3,4]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce and group them by the start date. This will give you the meetings that are grouped together.

```js
var meetings = [
  {
    "id": "1081",
    "endDate": "2020-03-24T12:30:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-24T12:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Meeting 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "1073",
    "endDate": "2020-03-24T13:00:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-24T12:30:00.000Z",
    "title": "Meeting 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "1082",
    "endDate": "2020-03-24T12:30:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-24T12:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Event 2",
  },
  {
    "id": "1083",
    "endDate": "2020-03-24T13:00:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-24T12:30:00.000Z",
    "description": "",
    "title": "event 1",
  },
  {

    "id": "1050",
    "endDate": "2020-03-25T13:00:00.000Z",
    "startDate": "2020-03-25T12:30:00.000Z",
    "title": "event 2",
  }
]

var grouped = meetings.reduce( function (obj, meeting) {
  var startDate = meeting.startDate
  obj[startDate] = obj[startDate] || []
  obj[startDate].push(meeting)
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(grouped)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the different dates
You can write such a function
with filter method

```
let arrayEvent1 = meetings.filter((el) => {
  return el.startDate === "2020-03-24T12:00:00.000Z"
});

let arrayEvent2 = meetings.filter((el) => {
  return el.startDate === "2020-03-24T12:30:00.000Z"
});
```

If you do not know you can use the solution of [@epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60834043/9161478)

This creates an array object with all the different sets of sessions

```
var grouped = meetings.reduce( function (obj, meeting) {
  var startDate = meeting.startDate
  obj[startDate] = obj[startDate] || []
  obj[startDate].push(meeting)
  return obj
}, {})
```

[image]

Comment: I want to make group of meeetings having same startDate.

Comment: You need group or one sort array?

Comment: I need two arrays: arr1 = [0,2] & arr2 = [1,3,4]

Comment: 3 not equal to  4  2020-03-24 !== 2020-03-25

Comment: My apologies. In that case, arr1 = [0,2] & arr2 = [1,3]

Comment: @KushalDesai I fix my answer